# How to instantiate an object within a linq query

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, instantiation

This is kinda theoretical question, 
I was looking at someone else' code (below) and my simple solution was to instantiate the collection outside linq, but I can guess there will be cases where I'd want to instantiate the objects inside the query, and perhaps only on a selection of elements.
Here's a simplified example of how this was being done (badly).

```
var pods = (from n in ids
where new Node(Convert.ToInt32(n)).HasValue("propertyName") 
select new
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(n),
    Url = new Node(Convert.ToInt32(n)).Url,
    Name = new Node(Convert.ToInt32(n)).Title()
}).ToList();
```

Irrelevant Note: in this case the Node constructor is getting data from a memory cache.

How can I improve this example to only instantiate each object once using linq?

Cheers.
Murray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `let` clause like this:

```
var pods = (
    from n in ids
    let id = Convert.ToInt32(n)
    let node = new Node(id)
    where node.HasValue("propertyName") 
    select new
    {
        Id = id,
        Url = node.Url,
        Name = node.Title()
    }
).ToList();
```

For more information please see [let clause (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx):

> In a query expression, it is sometimes
>   useful to store the result of a
>   sub-expression in order to use it in
>   subsequent clauses. You can do this
>   with the let keyword, which creates a
>   new range variable and initializes it
>   with the result of the expression you
>   supply. Once initialized with a value,
>   the range variable cannot be used to
>   store another value. However, if the
>   range variable holds a queryable type,
>   it can be queried.

Comment: Thanks, so simple. My google skills let me down and stack overflow picked me up :-)